# Need help to read specific line in a log which ends with specific word

Tags: java, file, file-read

I need help on java code to read a log file that can print all lines present ends with START word.

my file contains:

```
test 1 START
test2  XYZ
test 3 ABC
test 2 START
```

it should print

```
test 1 START
test 2 START
```

I tried below code but it printing START only.

```
 public class Findlog{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile"));
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(".*START$");
            // For each line of input, try matching in it.
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
              // For each match in the line, extract and print it.
              Matcher m = patt.matcher(line);
              while (m.find()) {
                // Simplest method:
                // System.out.println(m.group(0));

                // Get the starting position of the text

                System.out.println(line.substring(line));
              }
            }
```

Comment: String has a method called `endsWith`. Why not use that instead of regular expressions? Apart from that your current problem is simply that instead of printing the `line` that you read in you print the part of the line that your regular expression matched aka "START".

Comment: Thanks a lot  OH GOD SPIDERS , I used line and removed substring it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already found your solution.
Anyway a regex that should work is:

```
".*START$"
```

which says: take everithing (.*) that is followed by START and START is the end of the line ($)

Answer (score 3):

`line.endsWith("START")` check is good enough. You do not need regular expressions here.

Answer (score 0):

Full version of your code should look like below

```
     public class Findlog{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile"));
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
          // For each match in the line, extract and print it.
          if(line.endsWith("START"))
          {
             System.out.println(line);
          }
        }
```

If you want to skip case sensitivity, then the code should look like below.

```
public class Findlog{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile"));
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
          // For each match in the line, extract and print it.
          if(line.toLowerCase().endsWith(matches.toLowerCase()))
          {
             System.out.println(line);
          }
        }
```

Just change in the **if condition**.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Findlog{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile"));
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(".*START$");
            // For each line of input, try matching in it.
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
              // For each match in the line, extract and print it.
              Matcher m = patt.matcher(line);
              while (m.find()) {
                // Simplest method:
                // System.out.println(m.group(0));

                // Get the starting position of the text

                System.out.println(line.substring(line));
              }
            }
```